# RenderPartialViewToString set controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I am needing to get the result of a view and put in a variable. 
Researching SO, I found several examples and implemented according to the code below.

However, I want to spend the controller or the view "~ / Home / Acount", but today's code only amounts to the view controller.

What should I change to work to set and define the controller.

Code:

```
protected string RenderPartialViewToString(string viewName, object model)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(viewName))
        viewName = ControllerContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("action");

    ViewData.Model = model;

    using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
    {
        ViewEngineResult viewResult = ViewEngines.Engines.FindPartialView(ControllerContext, viewName);
        ViewContext viewContext = new ViewContext(ControllerContext, viewResult.View, ViewData, TempData, sw);
        viewResult.View.Render(viewContext, sw);

        return sw.GetStringBuilder().ToString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes i'm Necromancing, but I came across this unanswered post via google, so if it helps someone else:
The issue with your sample above is that you don't pass the ControllerContext from your calling controller method (which you can get by: `this.ControllerContext`) into this method.

Leaving your example above as:

```
protected string RenderPartialViewToString(ControllerContext context, string viewName, object model)
{
    var controller = context.Controller;

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(viewName))
        viewName = controller.ControllerContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("action");

    ViewData.Model = model;

    using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
    {
        ViewEngineResult viewResult = ViewEngines.Engines.FindPartialView(controller.ControllerContext, viewName);
        ViewContext viewContext = new ViewContext(controller.ControllerContext, viewResult.View, ViewData, TempData, sw);
        viewResult.View.Render(viewContext, sw);

        return sw.GetStringBuilder().ToString();
    }
}
```